# curl downloaded files always empty

Tags: c, curl

I tried to copy files with curl after the following example:

```
CURL *curl;
FILE *fp;
CURLcode res;
char *url = "http://localhost/aaa.txt";
char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "D:\\bbb.txt";

curl = curl_easy_init();

if(curl)
{
    fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

It  creates a file named `bbb.txt` but the file is empty. May you can help me? What's my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss a call to `curl_easy_perform`. See the [API description](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html) of it.